# Use if else in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to implement something of this sort using if else in Prolog.Being from C++ background I am finding it hard to implement.How can I do it???

```
if(X!=4 || Y!=3)
  printf("1");
else if(A!=4 || Y=3 && Z==2)
  printf("2");
```

Comment: `!!` should read `||`?

Comment: @ it means X is not equal to 4 OR Y is not equal to 3 in 1st if and 
in 2nd if it means X is not equal to 4 OR Y =3 AND Z equal to 2.
|| means OR in C++,&& means AND,! is negation

Comment: @Kay Oh sorry for that typo.

Comment: `X!=4` occurs in both conditions. If this is normal C code, then `X!=4` cannot be true in the second `if` block.

Comment: Oh sorry,I just wanted an example to convert these kinds of codes from C to Java,I have ediited the code now.Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If-else in Prolog is simply

```
Condition → Then ; Else
```

resp.

```
  Condition1 → Then1
; Condition2 → Then2
; …
; Else
```

Your C code

```
if(X!=4 || Y!=3)
    printf("1");
else if(A!=4 || Y==3 && Z==2)
    printf("2");
```

would translate to

```
  (X \= 4; Y \= 3)       -> write('1')
; (A \= 4; Y = 3, Z = 2) -> write('2')
; true   % or drop this line, then it will raise a unification error
```

But be aware that you should use [`write/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write/1) only in the outer loops, because the function is impure (the order of execution matters).

Probably you should write something like:

```
( (X \= 4; Y \= 3)       -> Message = '1'
; (A \= 4; Y = 3, Z = 2) -> Message = '2'),
write(Message).
```

---

Be aware that Prolog is a logical programming language. Ofttimes you will find that a verbatim translation from an imperative programming language is not the best solution.

As an example see a question I answered a few days ago: "[Calculating whether number is prime in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972392/calculating-whether-number-is-prime-in-prolog/25972640#25972640)":

Imperative:

```
is_prime(A) :-
    A > 1,                 % Negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime.
    is_prime(A, 2).        % Begin iteration:

is_prime(A, B) :-          % Test if A divides by B without remainder
    B >= A                 % The limit was reached?
    ->  true               %     Then it's prime.
    ;   0 is A mod B       % B divides A without a remainder?
    ->  false              %     Then it's not prime.
    ;   C is B + 1,        % Otherwise: C is B + 1
        is_prime(A, C).    % Test if C divides A.
```

Logical:

```
is_prime(A) :-
    L is A - 1,            % L is floor(sqrt(A))  ← optimized upper bound
    \+ (between(2, L, X),  % Is there a number X between 2 and L
        0 is A mod X).     % that divides A without a remainder?
```

Which is easier to read?

Comment: You should also mention that `Y` and `Z` might get unified. And that `<translated code with X unset>, X = 4` still yields `true` and prints `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit of code:

```
main:- (X\=4 ; Y\=3) -> write('1') ; 
       (A \=3 ; Y is 3 , Z is 2) -> write('2').
```

`\=` equals `!=`

`;` equals `||`
`,` equals `&&`
`is` equals `=`, but you can also use `=` for this.
`->` equals `then`

I added four `read/1` to test the code:

```
main:- read(X),read(Y),read(A),read(Z),
       (X\=4 ; Y\=3) -> write('1') ; 
       (A \=3 ; Y is 3 , Z is 2) -> write('2').
```

and I get:

```
3 ?- main.
|: 4.
|: 3.
|: 2.
|: 2.
2
true
```

Second `if` works

```
 6 ?- main.
|: 3.
|: 6.
1
true.
```

First `if` works